# Should I use Redux when component state is local

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component which has some local state (form validation error messages). This component does not get its state from a parent, nor does it passes these values to any of its children.

My application uses Redux for global state management. Should I push this state to be managed via Redux, or keep using local state for this particular component.

Comment: @Claies NO to the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is **NO**. -Simply because you already have all the necessary data in the only relevant component where you're actually using it.

**`Redux`** (*react-redux*) is used for **`app level state`** management.

So, here comes the longer answer -If you at some point decide that you need the data in various components and also that they need/ should be accessible at any point,  `Redux` is definitely a great option.

It all really depends on the amount of data and the need for effectively passing the data throughout the entire app.

On the other hand, if you only have to pass data between *`Parent - Children`* components, Redux could be an overkill, because you can still achieve it using just React by passing (exchange) values between various components via `props`.

So, if you only need that data inside only that component (**`Component level state`**), Redux it's a no-go because it's pretty large and it wouldn't be of any use for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the data is only needed for this component, so you don't need to push it to the Redux state.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you take the way of an immutable state and connected components and you would avoid unecessary re-render.

In this case, you can connect your field to it's state, and rerender the error message only when an error occur.

Answer (score 0):

I would not save this to Redux state. 
Unless you require this data elsewhere.

Comment: So my react-redux application can have local state in a form component and also a store manager to save global state. Is it perfectly fine having applied redux in my application but my application still have a local state in a component, would it defeat the purpose of implementing redux in my application as a whole since we implement redux to maintain all state centrally in store?

Comment: No you use redux to handle all state that needs to be shared. I wouldn't over kill it